# When I quit the application and then re-enter, my Hero works badly. Is there any way to fix this?

Tags: flutter-animation

I don't find any way to avoid this problem, implementing hero has never given me any problems.

I hope I was pretty clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I apologize. I will try to explain myself better: every time I exit the application and then return to it, the Hero animation does not work properly. Other times this happens even without exiting the application. The image enclosed by Hero is a .png that also changes size during the transition.